# How to create cxf endpoint in camel without soapaction header validation?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-camel, cxf

I'm trying to create service bus using camel and cxf component. Cxf endpoint should receive any soap  requests.

I have following snippet:

```
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    from("cxf://http://localhost:7778?dataFormat=PAYLOAD&properties.mtom-enabled=true")
      .process(new Processor {
        override def process(exchange: Exchange): Unit = {
          // do something here
        }
      })
  }
})
context.start
```

But during requests I get following error:

org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: The given SOAPAction queryINNFL does not match an operation

What can I do to make my endpoint receive all kind of soapaction headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to implement CXF Interceptor and connect it to the interceptor inbound chain to the proper place in the endpoint. The individual phases and examples are described [there](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html). Your interceptor implementation could then imitate the required `SoapAction` value, to match the wsdl.